# Is it possible to Linq Directly to a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a high speed application using a custom class (Price, Quantity, DateTime) inside of a List.  I either add to the list, if the Price is not found, or update it with Order Qty and DateTime and then run a query over the list to extract the top 4 occurrences, by order quantity, over and over again.  The code works great for the first half hour, then thousands of records later, bogs down.  I thought about trying a dictionary, because of the index, but can't figure out the update and Linq statements.

1. Is it possible to Linq directly to fields in a dictionary, say using a custom class or a struct, to extract the top 4 occurrences?  If so a short example would be great
2. Can I update a dictionary field directly after executing from a TryGetValue with the updated Order Qty and DateTime?
   If so a short example would be great
3. ...or is Dictionary NOT the way to proceed, remembering speed is of the essence?

Any help is appreciated.

```
List<PriceLevel> TrackPrice = new List<PriceLevel>();
        decimal loopLast=0;//sample only
        int loopLastQuantity=0;//sample only
        DateTime inputDateDT=DateTime.Now;//sample

        // Add or Update List
          var foundit = TrackPrice.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProgramPrice == loopLast);
                        if (foundit != null)// Found existing record

                        {
                            foundit.ProgramQuantity += loopLastQuantity;
                            foundit.ProgramLastTime = inputDateDT;
                        }
                        else // Add a new record
                        {
                            TrackPrice.Add(new PriceLevel
                            {
                                ProgramPrice = loopLast,
                                ProgramQuantity = loopLastQuantity,
                                ProgramLastTime = inputDateDT,

                            });
                        }
                    }
    // Query the List
         var finalFourQuantities = (from a in TrackPrice
                                               orderby a.ProgramQuantity descending
                                               where a.ProgramQuantity > 300000
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   a.ProgramPrice,
                                                   a.ProgramQuantity,
                                                   a.ProgramLastTime,
                                               }).Take(4);

                    foreach (var myprice in finalFourQuantities)
                    {   
                        //Process 4 order prices
                    }               

        public class PriceLevel
    {
        public decimal ProgramPrice         { get; set; }
        public int ProgramQuantity          { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProgramLastTime     { get; set; }// Last Order Time
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify the operations, their parameters and what they do. For instance, what do you mean by "Price is not found` - are you searching by Price? Also "top occurrences, by order quantity" - the items with higher quantity? etc.

Comment: Just so I understand, you're searching by Price, and if there are orders with that price, then you take the top 4 orders (by Quantity I suppose) for that price?

Comment: To answer your question's title, you can use LINQ to search in a Dictionary.  I think the bigger question is should you, or how should you really structure your data for efficient querying.

Comment: Right now in the List, I search for a Order Price, If not found, I add the Order Price, Order Qty and DateTime. If I find the Order Price I just Update the Order Qty and DateTime.  Every one second I query the List to find the 4 prices with  the largest order quantity and spit them out

Comment: Can you add code with your current operations that are using Lists? It will be easier to understand your requirements then.

Comment: You could have your dictionary key be Price and then keep a list of orders for that price as your dictionary value.  Not sure of the load and how often you flush that in memory repository, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply run a linq query over the Values property of the dictionary, treating it as any other `IEnumerable<T>`

Regarding the performance of your solution, you could try storing the 4 current top values in an array by themselves, then whenever a value is added/updated, you only need to compare the new value to the current top 4, swapping one out if the new value is greater. This will eliminate the need for a linear search of the entire data set.

Comment: now that's a smart approach. Why didn't I think of that Thanks everyone who contributed too!